# Image reloaded when scroll listView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying write a news list application. I had parsed JSON data from Server and created CustomListAdapter. There are three textView and imageView in my listView. It works great, image loaded and I set it to imageView. When scroll list view images are reloaded from server. This is my Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, container, false);
    this.drawerPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
    lv.addFooterView(v);
    isLoading = true;
    Http.getLists(aContext, this.drawerPosition, pageNumber, resultHandler);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
            if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
                // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
                isLoading = true;
                Http.getLists(aContext, drawerPosition, pageNumber, appendHandler);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void setListview() {
    listAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(aContext, arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

AsyncHttpResponseHandler resultHandler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        if (statusCode != 200)
            return;
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
            Log.d("JSON Result: ", json.toString());
            String result = json.getString("status");
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("complete")) {
                String pagenum = json.getString("pagenum");
                JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
                ArrayList<NewsList> s = new ArrayList<NewsList>();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    s.add(new NewsList(
                            Integer.parseInt(items.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID")),
                            items.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_date"),
                            items.getJSONObject(i).getString("category"),
                            items.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_title"),
                            items.getJSONObject(i).getString("image")
                    ));
                }
                arrayList = s;
                isLoading = false;
                pageNumber = Integer.valueOf(pagenum) + 1;
                setListview();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        String answ = error.getLocalizedMessage();
        Log.d("API", answ);
    }
};
```

This is my Custom ListView Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.nDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listDate);
        holder.nCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
        holder.nImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    if (newsList.get(position) != null) {
        holder.imageUrl = newsList.get(position).image;
        holder.nTitle.setText(newsList.get(position).title);
        holder.nCategory.setText(newsList.get(position).category);
        holder.nDate.setText(Base.getInstance(context).getDateString(newsList.get(position).date));
        if (holder.imageUrl != null && !holder.imageUrl.equals("null")) {
            String thumbUrl = holder.imageUrl.substring(0, holder.imageUrl.lastIndexOf('.')) + "-260x145" + holder.imageUrl.substring(holder.imageUrl.lastIndexOf('.'), holder.imageUrl.length());
            imageView = holder.nImage;
            setImage(thumbUrl);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nTitle;
    TextView nDate;
    TextView nCategory;
    ImageView nImage;
    String imageUrl;
}

public void setImage(String imageUrl) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(imageUrl, null, fileHandler);
}

FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler fileHandler = new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(context) {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable,
                          File response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(response.getPath()));
    }
};
```

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: You are not effectively using View Holder pattern. Every time Listview scroll it will create new ViewHolder Object, In which your image data will not be there. Thats why image will be realod on every listview scroll. Please take a look on http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html tutorial.

Comment: Dhaval Patel I read this tutorial, and renewed code but it not helped. Image is reloading every time when scroll.

Comment: @iProgrammer Please update your code so we can take a look on your new code.

Comment: I had updated new code. Please check out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code, It might help you to resolve your problem.

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends..{

   //Map to cache Image Bitmap. Key= imageUrl,value =Image Bitmap
   private Map<String, Bitmap> mBitmapCache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();    

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;

      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          holder.nTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
          holder.nDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listDate);
          holder.nCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
          holder.nImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
          convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      } 

      if (newsList.get(position) != null) {
          holder.imageUrl = newsList.get(position).image;
          holder.nTitle.setText(newsList.get(position).title);
          holder.nCategory.setText(newsList.get(position).category);
          holder.nDate.setText(Base.getInstance(context).getDateString(newsList.get(position).date));
          if (holder.imageUrl != null && !holder.imageUrl.equals("null")) {
               String thumbUrl = holder.imageUrl.substring(0, holder.imageUrl.lastIndexOf('.')) + "-260x145" + holder.imageUrl.substring(holder.imageUrl.lastIndexOf('.'), holder.imageUrl.length());
               holder.setImage(thumbUrl);
          }
      }
      return convertView;
   }

   private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView nTitle;
        TextView nDate;
        TextView nCategory;
        ImageView nImage;
        String imageUrl;

        public void setImage(String imageUrl) {
           this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
           Bitmap imageBitmap = mBitmapCache.get(imageUrl);
           if(imageBitmap!=null){
               nImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
           } else {
               AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
               client.get(imageUrl, null, fileHandler);
           }
        }

        FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler fileHandler = new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(context) {
             @Override
             public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable,
                      File response) {
             }

             @Override
             public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
                   Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(response.getPath());
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                   mBitmapCache.put(imageUrl, imageBitmap);         
             }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me. You wrote incorrect imageBitmap.put(imageUrl, imageBitmap). It must be mBitmapCache.put(imageUrl, imageBitmap);

Answer (score 0):

Your code in

```
public void setImage() {
    if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.equals("null") && !imageUrl.equals("")) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(imageUrl, null, fileHandler);
    }
}
```

looks suspicious: any valid URL will force a reloading as it matches all three conditions in

```
    imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.equals("null") && !imageUrl.equals("")
```

Example:
http://www.google.com/logo.png is not null, does not equal the string "null" nor the string "", so the if will always be true and the AsyncLoader created.
BTW, checking for "null" only makes sense if you are explicitly using that somewhere else in your code. Most probably you only want to check for the null value, not the "null" string.